# Change single text area with multiple div and change the div image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have text in the area 'Pinctitle'. I want this to change each time one of the Pselectorbuttons is hovered on with a fade. At the same time I want the 'Pselectorbutton' to change the image inside it.

Currently I have it set to be a background image. I was going to attempt to achieve this with hover, but I understand that it has to be a related div so I assume I may need to bring some Jquery in to my page.

Can this be done entirely in CSS?

```css
 .Pselectorinside {
     position: relative;
    }
    
    .Pincludes {
     font-size: 12px;
    }
    
    .Pinctitle {
     font-size: 21px;
    }
    
    .Pselectorrow {
     width: 100%;
     margin-left: -21px;
    }
    
    .Pselectorbutton {
     float: left;
     width: 30px;
     height: 30px;
     margin-left: 21px;
     background-color: blue;
    }
    
    .Pselectorbutton .one{
     background-image: url(../images/oneA.jpg)
    }
    
    .Pselectorbutton .one:hover{
     background-image: url(../images/oneB.jpg)
    }
    
    .Pselectorbutton .two{
     background-image: url(../images/twoA.jpg)
    }
    
    .Pselectorbutton .two:hover{
     background-image: url(../images/twoB.jpg)
    }
    
    .Pselectorbutton .three{
     background-image: url(../images/threeA.jpg)
    }
    
    .Pselectorbutton .three{
     background-image: url(../images/threeB.jpg)
    }
```

```html
    <div class="Pselectorinside">
        <div class="Pincludes">PROJECT INCLUDES
        </div>
        <div class="Pinctitle">Photography
        </div>
        <div class="Pselectorrow">
            <div class="Pselectorbutton one">
            </div>
            <div class="Pselectorbutton two">
            </div>
            <div class="Pselectorbutton three">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xjxq7tb/)

```
var originalTitle = $('.Pinctitle').text();

$('body').on('mouseenter', '.Pselectorbutton', function(){
    var text = $(this).data('title');
    $('.Pinctitle').text(text);
});
$('body').on('mouseleave', '.Pselectorbutton', function(){
    $('.Pinctitle').text(originalTitle);
});
```

Comment: Very much like this thanks. What about the images changing themselves? I also want them to have fades between to match some other features I have implemented on the site.